# No callback function and button submit 2Captcha and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, 2captcha

I'm trying to learn how to write programs using python and combining selenium with the 2captcha API.
Working on code from another topic that obviously works. I was able to learn this a little. 
below is the code I'm learning

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import requests


GChrome=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\driverswebs\geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64\geckodriver.exe")
GChrome.get('https://www.mercadobitcoin.com.br/conta/login/')

box_login = GChrome.find_element_by_name('cpfcnpj')
box_login.send_keys('my_cpf')
box_pass = GChrome.find_element_by_name('password')
box_pass.send_keys('my_pass')

box_pass.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


# 2Captcha service
service_key = '7dccd1' # 2captcha service key
google_site_key = '6LfIxCoUAAAAAEEW7DQK_gj3pzzeJz82dTW_SMNH'
pageurl = 'https://www.mercadobitcoin.com.br/conta/login/'
url = "http://2captcha.com/in.php?key=" + service_key + "&method=userrecaptcha&googlekey=" + google_site_key + "&pageurl=" + pageurl
resp = requests.get(url)

if resp.text[0:2] != 'OK':
    quit('Service error. Error code:' + resp.text)
captcha_id = resp.text[3:]

fetch_url = "http://2captcha.com/res.php?key="+ service_key + "&action=get&id=" + captcha_id

for i in range(1, 10):
    time.sleep(5) # wait 5 sec.
    resp = requests.get(fetch_url)
    if resp.text[0:2] == 'OK':
        break

GChrome.execute_script('var element=document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response"); element.style.display="";')

GChrome.execute_script("""
  document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = arguments[0]
""", resp.text[3:])

GChrome.execute_script("""
  onSubmit(arguments[0])
""", resp.text[3:])
```

the above code works but if we have the onSubbmit button which has callback functions
what if we don't have them ? According to the 2Captcha API, when there is no button, find the ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0] .aa.l.callback parameter in the code and refer to it.

Only in my case there is no Callback parameter and how to send the received tokken in this case?
below the code fragmet ___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0]

[image]

I will be grateful for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

There must be callback function anyways. You need to track the requests in browser after manual captcha solving and then perform them in your program.
More information about how to find and execute a callback function you can find here:
https://2captcha.com/2captcha-api#callback
https://captchaforum.com/threads/problem-with-invisible-recaptcha-v2-callback-function-at-mail-com-sign-up-page.56/
Ensure that you've checked all sub-branches of the elements and all the requests.

Comment: I was looking and still couldn't find the callback function :(

Comment: Try to check all the requests in browser's Network Monitor or with any special software (like Fiddler). There must be an answer somewhere.